# Android Realm save one-to-many models with autoincrement id

Tags: android, realm

I try use Realm for android. I have models:

```
public class Product extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Category category;
```

and

```
public class Category extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    long id;
    private String code;
    private String name;

    @LinkingObjects("category")
    private final RealmResults<Product> products = null;
```

I try persist list of products:

```
public void saveProducts(List<Product> products) {

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(realm1 -> {

            for (Product product : products) {
                Number currentIdNum = realm1.where(Product.class).max("id");
                long nextId;
                if(currentIdNum == null) {
                    nextId = 1;
                } else {
                    nextId = currentIdNum.intValue() + 1;
                }
                product.setId(nextId);
                realm1.insertOrUpdate(product);
            }
        });
        realm.close();
    }
```

All products persist but categore created with one id. id = 0;

How can I correctly create an id for Category and save(Cascade.ALL in hiberhate)

Generally I do not understand how this realm works? Could not autoincrement be normal? everything is so crooked.

Comment: If you didn't set the value of the `category.id` to anything, then it is initialized to `0`, and therefore `0` will be saved.

Comment: thank you captain of the obvious. That's why I'm asking how to correctly create this

Comment: Set the category ID that is inside the `product` if it's `0` before calling `insertOrUpdate` on the product?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I do not understand you. can you give an example how can you save such an object at all?

Comment: ()How did you update values for `Category` now? `insertOrUpdate` will create an object if the pk doesn't exist, otherwise it will update the current object with the same pk to the new values.